# Is there a way to query a RTDB list on the new web SDK and simply get the value instead of snapshot changes?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm jumping between angularfire, rxfire and firebase-sdk docs and I can't find an answer.

With version 8 of the firebase-sdk API I could simply query RTDB and get the result of my query (not a bunch of snapshot changes). How can I do that with the new API ?

I couldn't find it on any of those docs. Is it possible via angularfire ? rxfire ? firebase-sdk ?

I'm trying to bind a ngFor to the result of my query. I don't want to have to manually handle child_added, child_removed, child_changed, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `angular/fire 7` is still largely incomplete which can be frustrating when trying to build a project with it. To get a node list from RTDB and display it with an `ngFor` loop you can do the following

imports:

```ts
import {Database, listVal, ref} from "@angular/fire/database";
```

declare observable:

```ts
  rtdb: Observable<any[] | null> | undefined;
```

constructor:

```ts
  constructor(private database: Database) {}
```

function to return the data:

```ts
  async getNodeList() {
    const nodeRef = ref(this.database, 'path/to/node/list');

    this.rtdb = listVal(nodeRef);

    this.rtdb.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

your HTML template:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of rtdb | async">
  {{ item| json }}
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've tried that but it feels VERY buggy. It randomly fails to load the data, or load it but don't watch/update

Comment: @Maslow The v9 sdk is only about a month old, and angular/fire 7 even newer. While it's a great update and important to become familiar with it, it's still full of bugs. I don't recommend using it for a production app quite yet

Comment: I think you're right. Thanks again

Comment: how do you query using listVal ?